# expanding exponential with sympy

Tags: sympy, expand

I'm trying to factor an exponential, so that 
exp((x+y)/z) = exp(x/z) + exp(y/z).

Here's my attempt:

```
import sympy as sympy
x,y,z = sympy.symbols('x,y,z')
sympy.expand_power_exp(sympy.exp((x+y)/z))
```

which did not result in any expansion (I got a result of exp((x+y)/z)).

I'm curious if I need to state some assumptions or use a different approach?

Comment: I found a kludgy solution:

`sympy.expand_power_exp(sympy.exp(sympy.expand(sympy.exp((x+y)/z).args[0])))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Expansion as desired works with the generic `expand` call:

```
>>> exp((x+y)/z).expand()
exp(x/z)*exp(y/z)
```

If you want to be more targeted, you have to expand the `Mul` first:

```
>>> expand_mul(exp((x+y)/z))
exp(x/z + y/z)
>>> expand_power_exp(_)
exp(x/z)*exp(y/z)
```